# Yii2, хранение файлов

Tags: yii2

Всем привет. Подскажите, как в yii2 решить вопрос с тем что бы загружаемые файлы хранились на отдельном для этого развернутом сервере. Т.е. web приложение один сервер, а файловик другой.

Comment: Какая операционная система используется на этих серверах?

Comment: @ZhukovRoman  Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По данному вопросу вам может помочь [этот](https://github.com/yii2tech/file-storage) компонент. Он позволяет хранить фалы на удаленных серверах.

Для его использования необходимо добавить в конфиг приложения следующее :

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'fileStorage' => [
            'class' => 'yii2tech\filestorage\local\Storage',
            'basePath' => '@webroot/files',
            'baseUrl' => '@web/files',
            'filePermission' => 0777,
            'buckets' => [
                'tempFiles' => [
                    'baseSubPath' => 'temp',
                    'fileSubDirTemplate' => '{^name}/{^^name}',
                ],
                'imageFiles' => [
                    'baseSubPath' => 'image',
                    'fileSubDirTemplate' => '{ext}/{^name}/{^^name}',
                ],
            ]
        ],
        // ...
    ],
    // ...
];
```

После чего его можно будет использовать следующим образом :

```
bucket = Yii::$app->fileStorage->getBucket('tempFiles');

$bucket->saveFileContent('foo.txt', 'Foo content'); // create file with content
$bucket->deleteFile('foo.txt'); // deletes file from bucket
$bucket->copyFileIn('/path/to/source/file.txt', 'file.txt'); // copy file into the bucket
$bucket->copyFileOut('file.txt', '/path/to/destination/file.txt'); // copy file from the bucket
var_dump($bucket->fileExists('file.txt')); // outputs `true`
echo $bucket->getFileUrl('file.txt'); // outputs: 'http://domain.com/files/f/i/file.txt'
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/113036)

Comment: @Elena если бы вы на минутку задумались, а не машинально выполняли обязанность модераторскую, то заметили бы, что ссылка ведет на главную страницу библиотеки гитхаба, на которой отображается информация из readme файла. Очевидно, что этот порядок врядли изменится в ближайшее время, а если автор библотеки изменит или удалит описание библиотеки, то и тут она станет неактуальна!